# How to run php strlen function on entire array?

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I have an array of strings, and I want to find the sum of the lengths of all the strings in the array. Eg:

```
$array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
```

strlen result is

```
3 3 5
```

and the sum is `11`. How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried - if you can get the length of each item you can add them together.

Comment: Hint: Use `array_map` + `strlen` and also `array_sum`.

Comment: You could implode the array: `echo strlen(implode("", $array));`.

Comment: What _exactly_ did you do to get that output? strlen doesn't work on arrays directly. So presumably you ran it separately on each item in the array? If so, have you tried simply adding the results together to get the total??! Demo: https://3v4l.org/aYWZf . Or as the others said, you can do slightly fancier stuff with other built-in PHP functions to get similar output - did you do any additional research? The question is both unclear (due to incomplete code) and apparently poorly-researched. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve your experience in future.

Comment: @Foobar `$total = array_sum(array_map('strlen', $array));`? This is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
echo $total_str_length = array_sum(array_map('strlen', $array));
```

**O/P :** 11